# C# forward mouse events to another window without losing focus

Tags: c#, windows, mouseevent

My app screencaptures another window that runs on a second monitor. Now I'd also like to forward mouse clicks made in my app to that window. I tried using `SendMessage` in **user32.dll** for this, but this also makes window focus switch, which causes some issues, like the two windows rapidly fighting for focus. Is there are way to place those mouse events without making the hidden window active and losing focus on the main app?

Comment: [System.Windows.Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation)

Comment: Isn't this something I'd need to integrate in the second program? Unfortunately, I don't have the sourcecode and it's probably not even written in C#.

Comment: Nope, you use UI Automation from your app to automate another, running, application. Which includes activating default actions (clicking Buttons, opening Menus and activating a menu item, changing  text etc.). UI Automation doesn't require the *controlled* app to be active, or in the same Screen, or even visible (doesn't mean *disabled*).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there are way to place those mouse events without making the hidden window active and losing focus on the main app?

No, there is not even a way to forward mouse input to another receiver. Messages are only part of the input processing. The system also does internal bookkeeping and you cannot replicate that.

The only reliable way to inject input is by calling [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput). Doing so doesn't allow you to specify a receiver. Input goes to whichever thread is determined to be the receiver by the system.

Although, more often than not, this question is asked when the problem that needs to be solved is a different one altogether: How do you automate a UI? The answer to that question is [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).